# Is it a true hyperbolic icosahedron?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Take a regular icosahedron. For each face, take the image of the circumcenter of the icosahedron by the reflection about the plane containing the face. Now subtract the sphere centered at this point with radius the circumradius to the icosahedron. Here is the result:

[image]

Is it a true hyperbolic icosahedron?

There's a second question. This construction does not work for a regular tetrahedron (the result is far from being a hyperbolic tetrahedron). Why?

Comment: May be a William Thurston's geometry modification:  
 https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/getting-into-shapes/

Comment: Your question is incomplete. This object, by construction, is a subset of Euclidean space. But Euclidean space is not hyperbolic space. For that reason alone I could formally answer "No, this is not a true hyperbolic icosahedron". I suspect, however, that your intention is to somehow embed this object into hyperbolic space, and then to ask whether the image of that embedding is a true hyperbolic icosahedron. If this is so, can you explain what embedding you had in mind?

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm considering the Poincaré ball. Not sure this answers your question? Because that sounds obvious... And by the way now I think the answer is obviously "yes", because the faces are spherical triangles. But I don't master hyperbolic geometry and I'm not able to make a clear explanation of my thought...

Comment: @LeeMosher Here is a way to complete/correct the question: "Let $O$ denote the center of a Euclidean regular icosahedron. Is it true that there exists a radius $r>0$ such that the solid defined above is a regular hyperbolic icosahedron in the hyperbolic 3-space realized as a Euclidean ball of radius $r$ and center $O$ and a metric conformal to the Euclidean metric?" This question has a negative answer (which is a computation reducing the problem to spherical trigonometry).